# error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed

Tags: git, bitbucket

Fui clonar um repositório no Bitbucket, porém apareceu esse error

> error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read datab remaining  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   fatal: early EOF
>    fatal: index-pack failed

O que poderia ser feito para resolver?

Comment: Este repositório que quer clonar é bem grande?

Comment: Não, me parece que foi alguma limitação que tinha na minha conexão.

Comment: Faz sentido. Acredito que conexões lentas possam causar isto. O problema foi resolvido sozinho então?

Comment: Sim não voltou acontecer

Comment: Legal! Se quiser, forneça uma resposta então para sua própria pergunta, explicando que o problema resolveu sozinho e que você acredita que seja a conexão :)

Comment: Ok, obrigado, depois colocarei uma resposta estou um pouco ocupado agora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi uma instabilidade com o servidor do serviço.